# DevDays 2011: What equipment is recommended for note-taking and participation?

Tags: discussion, policy, devdays-2011

So, I'm registered for DevDays 2011 in Washington DC. Yay! Now I'm starting to think about what I need to bring with me to get the maximum benefit from the event.

This is the first conference of its type that I'll be attending. I've been to non-programming conferences, and I've been to classroom-style training events, but I get the feeling DevDays won't be quite the same. I want to know what sort of equipment will be needed/necessary to get the most benefit from the program. Specifically:

- **Is bringing a laptop recommended?** Will laptop users be able to follow along with code being discussed and play with what they're learning in real time? If not, is laptop note-taking encouraged? Will there even be desk-space/power/etc enough to make having a laptop practical? Would pen-and-paper be better?
- **Is recording of the event permitted?** - Even if I don't bring a laptop, I could see how recording via my phone or MP3 player or other device could be beneficial. If it's allowed, that is.
- **Will any of the tutorials and talks be made available in an electronic format?** - If Joel and Jeff plan to put all the talks on YouTube after the conference, or distribute recordings to attendees on CD or something, detailed note-taking might not be as important.

Does anyone know the answer to these questions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because DevDays 2011 never happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DevDays is an educational experience for everyone involved (especially us) - so yes, we want people to be able to retain all of the things they learn.

1) Yes, laptops are recommended (if you so desire) - in fact, we'll be providing lots of classroom style seating with tables so you even have somewhere to put the laptop (as opposed to your lap).

2) **Some** of the talks will *probably* be made available online after the conference.  We won't decide which ones or how many until later, but the only way to get ALL of the content is to be there as we will not be making everything available online.

3) Yes, recording AUDIO only of the talks is permitted.  Video recording tends to get disruptive to the rest of the audience (with people holding up cameras/standing/fiddling with them/etc) so we'll be asking people not to record video.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Get a [Recording Pen](http://www.livescribe.com/en-us/), and record it while you take notes.  The audio is linked to the notes, so you can start listening by clicking on the words.

Answer (score 2):

> Is bringing a laptop recommended? Will laptop users be able to follow along with code being discussed and play with what they're learning in real time? If not, is laptop note-taking encouraged? Will there even be desk-space/power/etc enough to make having a laptop practical? Would pen-and-paper be better?

Only if you can type really fast. I might suggest a flash-less camera, but that sort of ties in with the following point... (however a pen and sturdy pad are highly encouraged)

> Is recording of the event permitted? - Even if I don't bring a laptop, I could see how recording via my phone or MP3 player or other device could be beneficial. If it's allowed, that is.

afaik that will be permitted. Additionally, I should imagine that the team would be recording the events, but idk for sure. If you don't have an answer in 2 weeks I will ;)

> Will any of the tutorials and talks be made available in an electronic format? - If Joel and Jeff plan to put all the talks on YouTube after the conference, or distribute recordings to attendees on CD or something, detailed note-taking might not be as important.

They should be yes. The talk-givers usually list a URL on any presentations that are given.